# Google Sheets Named Functions - cell references are absolute?

Tags: google-sheets, named-function

I thought I was onto an excellent way to re-use cell formulas - but came up against the named function editor being determined to mangle anything I entered into absolute cell references - so I couldn't drag cells containing my named formula and have it use relative references internally

eg., $C2 became $C$2 so all rows referred to the same data on the same row

do I need to mangle things and treat my formula as text, somehow find the row or range in which the formula is being called and dig out the row etc etc

disappointing after an hour or so....

Comment: It's not clear what are you asking. If you want some help, probably there's a workaround, but we need more information (formula, context, desired results)

Comment: It would be better if you could provide a sample sheet with test data, where the community can replicate the issue to fully grasp what you are experiencing. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Relative cell references are handled by using Function parameters

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wzBC1D58q585tX5GYLO_BIS8LSSc22h5DcPFnKZ2fp0/edit?usp=sharing